# Parse Fetching All Columns In Parse User

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get `CurrentUser` in my `iOS` app. And I though parse fetches all the `Columns` belonging to the `CurrentUser`. So, I have a pointer to a `Address Table` called `defaultAddress`. So, I tried to access an attribute in the `Address` it and I was having null data while accessing it by doing `User.currentUser()?.defaultAddress.city`. But, when I `print(User.currentUser()?.defaultAddress)` I get this `Optional(<Address: 0x7f9fd27549a0, objectId: OZVqUbU15j, localId: (null)> {
})`

This is my address Model

```
 class Address: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}

static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Address"
}

@NSManaged var zip: String
@NSManaged var city: String
@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var street1: String
@NSManaged var phone: String
@NSManaged var state: String
@NSManaged var country: String
@NSManaged var owner: User
@NSManaged var isValid: Bool
}
```

It's like the `defaultAddress` in the `User` model is not fetched

Answer (score 0):

In pointer fields, Parse fetches empty objects (containing only objectId) by default. If you want to get object with related objects included, you need to *include* the key in query.

Since you can't change how CurrentUser is fetched/updated, you will have to make your own find/get Query and use `query.includeKey("defaultAddress")` method to get full Address object. See [docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-relational-queries) for more info and examples.